# Change color of existing polygons onRender function htmlWidgets Leaflet

Tags: javascript, shiny, leaflet, htmlwidgets, r-leaflet

So I am trying to create a choropleth map of all the counties in the United States where the counties will be colored based on a variety of different variables (e.g. unemployment rate, poverty rate, etc.)

Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage("Mapping Characteristics of the USA",
           fluidRow(
                    column(10, leafletOutput("map")),
                    column(2, radioButtons(inputId = "radio", selected=character(0), label="Characteristics",
                                           choiceNames = c("Unemployment Rate", "% w/out high school education", "% w/out insurance"),
                                           choiceValues = c("uer", "no_hs_per", "no_insur")))))

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  #Render the map
  output$map = renderLeaflet({leaflet(counties)})

   observeEvent(input$radio,
       { 
         #Create color function
         pal = colorBin(palette = topo.colors(10), domain = counties[[input$radio]], pretty=TRUE)

         #Redraw Map
         m = leafletProxy("map", session=session, data=counties) %>% clearShapes() %>%
           addPolygons(stroke=TRUE, weight=1, fillOpacity = 0.5, color = pal(counties[[input$radio]]))
       }) #End of observeEvent(input$radio, ...)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem is every time a user clicks on a new radio button the leaflet map redraws the entire polygon layer. This can take a while, and it doesn't create a seamless user experience. What I would like to be able to do is simply edit the color of the already existing polygon layer.

Using pseudo code, it might look like some thing like this...

```
#Create the map where every county is initially blue
output$map = renderLeaflet({
             leaflet(counties) %>% addPolygons(stroke=TRUE, weight=1, fillOpacity = 0.5, color = "blue", group="Counties")
 })

observeEvent(input$radio,
 {
    #Create color function
    pal = colorBin(palette = topo.colors(10), domain = counties[[input$radio]], pretty=TRUE)

    #Edit the already existing counties group
    m = leafletProxy("map", session=session, data=counties) %>% setStyle(group = "Counties", newColor = pal(counties[[input$radio]]))
 })
```

I believe something like this could be done by adding in some Javascript. On the Leaflet for R tutorial page, they mention the onRender() function from htmlwidgets as a way to introduce Javascript (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/morefeatures.html).

On the documentation page for the Leaflet Javascript package, there is also a setStyle() function which would do what I want, I think (an example of it in use can be found here http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/).

The only problem is I am hopelessly lost when it comes to Javascript. If somebody could point me in the right direction on how to add Javascript to my above script to get it to work that way I want, that would be great.

Also if anyone knows of any other packages, mapping tools, etc. to create the map I want which might be easier than what I am currently doing, I am eager to hear about them.

Two examples of kind of what I want to do:
http://www.nytimes.com/projects/census/2010/explorer.html
https://www.socialexplorer.com/a9676d974c/explore

Comment: Have you looked at the `crosstalk` package?  It allows very fast interaction between widgets.  (The CRAN version won't highlight polygons, but there are a couple of patches among the PRs on Github that enable this.)

Comment: I am not 100% certain crosstalk can help me with this issue. But thanks for your suggestion. I am investigating it now. To install a specific pull request, is the command simply devtools::install_github("rstudio/leaflet", pull=391)?

Comment: I think it's `devtools::install_github("rstudio/leaflet", ref = devtools::github_pull(391))` (but I'm not a Github expert).

Comment: Thanks! I just used this pull request. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be fully featured enough for me to use it. But I also don't think it perfectly aligns with what I want to do either.

Comment: without a reproducible example, we can't run your code.